# Which GPU would be default to use by Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have two GPUs installed in my computer. When I run my code, I always saw the debug information from Tensorflow, it will display the information of  my two GPU cards. While, which one would be used if I did not specify for TF?  If I have multiple GPU cards, whether I need to specify one GPU for TF for the efficiencies. Thank you~!

Comment: by default tensorflow only uses one gpu, if you want to make use of multi gpus you need to manually specify which operations run on which device with code like `with tf.devide("/gpu:1"):`. A multi gpu training example can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)

Comment: If I have two GPU cards, which one would be used by TF?

Comment: I don't know, one of there two cards will be picked up by tensorflow according to some rules.

Comment: I have tested them and found, both memory would be employed while one one card is used for calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow uses every available GPU on your system.

If you have 2 GPUs and Tensorflow sees both, it will allocate the same memory on both devices and it will use some scheduling algorithm to swap elements from one GPU memory to the other when it's needed.

You can decide in which GPU execute a specified operation using the `with tf.device("/gpu:<number>")` context manager. However the memory is allocated in every GPU present.

If you want, instead, use only some GPU and avoid the allocation of anything on any other, you have to use the CUDA environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.

Before executing your python script, you can specify the CPU that Tensorflow will see. In that way you're sure that only some device will be used.

For instance, if you want that Tensorflow sees only your 2nd GPU you can run your script in that way:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python execute_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to set the GPU choices inside your Python code if you don't want to `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` or add `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python xx.py` everytime before running your code:

```
# Set GPU
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = flags.gpu_choice
```

`flags.gpu_choice` could be a string like `'0,1,2'`

Then you can simply follow Tensorflow's tutorial on [Use GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) to:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```